# Creating text files with comma separated list of values from one column based on shared value in second column from the commandline

Tags: text-processing, csv

I am hoping to create a series of text files each containing a comma separated list of values from column 1 of an input file based on their shared value in column 2 of the input file.

Input file format:

```
CB-03-01-01     CB-03.1
CB-03-01-02     CB-03.1
CB-03-01-03     CB-03.1
CB-03-02-01     CB-03.2
CB-03-02-02     CB-03.2
CB-03-02-03     CB-03.2
CB-08-01        CB-08
CB-08-02        CB-08
CB-08-03        CB-08
```

Desired outputs:
CB-03.1.txt

```
CB-03-01-01,CB-03-01-02,CB-03-01-03
```

CB-03.2.txt

```
CB-03-02-01,CB-03-02-02,CB-03-02-03
```

CB-08.txt

```
CB-08-01,CB-08-02,CB-08-03
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you can use is:

```
awk '{a[$2]=a[$2]","$1} END {for(i in a) print substr(a[i],2) >i".txt"}' input_file
```

`a` is associative array and `substr` function remove the leading comma from first assignment of the array element.

As per comment you may need to replace `>i".txt"` with `>(i".txt"); close(i".txt")` with some versions of `awk` and to close open file handlers

Comment: `print ... >i".txt"` will give you a syntax error in some awks, it needs to be `print >(i".txt")` to work in all awks, and not closing the output files as you go will lead to a "too many open" files error in most awks and a significant slowdown in others if you cross some threshold. Storing all of the values in an array will potentially use up a lot of memory unnecessarily.

Comment: @EdMorton, right, usage of memory may become big. But there is always tradeoffs, CPU, memory, disk...

Comment: If you change `for(i in a) print substr(a[i],2) >i".txt"` into `for(i in a) { print substr(a[i],2) >(i".txt"); close(i".txt") }` it'll solve both the portability and too many open files issues with no tradeoffs other than writing an extra 20 chars or so.

Comment: @EdMorton, about tradeoffs I mean memory usage if many `keys` for array :)

Comment: @EdMorton, what I mean script can be like this: `awk '{printf"%s" $1"," >>($2".txt"); close($2".txt")}' ` where memory is not in use but the load is directed to I/O operations

Comment: Yes, that is also a way it could be done but, as you point, out it'd be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %h; for lines() { %h.push: .[1] => .[0] given .split(/ \s+ /) };
            for %h.sort() { 
                spurt( ( .key ~ ".txt" ).IO, $_.value.join(",") ~ "\n", createonly => True);
            };'  file.txt
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programmming languages. An advantage of Raku is high-level support for Unicode.

Basically the problem as stated is a `key`/`value` problem, wherein all key/value pairs are stored in a `%h` hash. Every time you see a new second column (text) element you create a `key`, adding the corresponding first column (text) element as `value`. Since `keys` in a hash are maintained unique, subsequent `value`s for the same `key` get `push`ed (or `append`ed) to the same `key`.

*Instead of taking input off the command line, you can write the code below which has the appropriate path hardcoded inside:*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $in = "/path/to/file.txt".IO; my %h;
            for $in.lines() { %h.push: .[1] => .[0] given .split(/ \s+ /) };
            for %h.sort() { 
                my $out = IO::Spec::Unix.catpath($, $in.dirname, .key) ~ ".txt"; 
                spurt( $out,  $_.value.join(",") ~ "\n", createonly => True) };'
```

Other options include saving the code immediately above (inside the single quotes) as a script, and calling it at the command line with `raku script.raku`. Note above, the hardcoded script can be ported to other OSes, simply by changing the `IO::Spec` call as appropriate (to `IO::Spec::Win32`, `IO::Spec::Cygwin`, etc.).

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap#Mutable_hashes_and_immutable_maps
https://docs.raku.org/routine/split
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk (untested):

```
awk '
    $2 != prev {
        if ( out != "" ) {
            print "" > out
            close(out)
        }
        out = $2 ".txt"
        sep = ""
        prev = $2
    }
    {
        printf "%s%s", sep, $1 > out
        sep = ","
    }
    END {
        if ( out != "" ) {
            print "" > out
        }
    }
' file
```

The above only has 1 output file open at a time and so can't run into a "too many open files" error (or slowdown) and only stores 1 line at a time in memory so it'll continue to work no matter how large your input file is.

It does assume your input is grouped by the `$2` values as in the example you provided but if that's not the case in your real data then just sort it by the 2nd field first, e.g. `sort -k2,2 file | awk 'script'`.